# C# return generic list of objects using linq

Tags: c#, linq, filter, generic-list

i got a generic list that looks like this:

```
List<PicInfo> pi = new List<PicInfo>();
```

PicInfo is a class that looks like this:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class PicInfo
{
        [ProtoMember(1)]
        public string fileName { get; set; }
        [ProtoMember(2)]
        public string completeFileName { get; set; }
        [ProtoMember(3)]
        public string filePath { get; set; }
        [ProtoMember(4)]
        public byte[] hashValue { get; set; }

        public PicInfo() { } 
}
```

what i'm trying to do is:

- first, filter the list with duplicate file names and return the duplicate objects;
- than, filter the returned list with duplicate hash value's;

i can only find examples on how to do this which return anonymous types. but i need it to be a generic list.

if someone can help me out, I'd appreciate it. also please explain your code. it's a learning process for me.

thanks in advance!

[EDIT]

the generic list contains a list of objects. these objects are pictures. every picture has a file name, hash value (and some more data which is irrelevant at this point). some pictures have the same name (duplicate file names). and i want to get a list of the duplicate file names from this generic list 'pi'.

But those pictures also have a hash value. from the file names that are identical, i want another list of those identical files names that also have identical hash values.

[/EDIT]

Comment: You should describe your input+output better. What do you mean by filtering a list on duplicate filenames? What shape should the result have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you have to use SequenceEqual method for finding dublicate
(http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb348567.aspx).
For filter use

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should work. Whether it is the best method I am not sure. It is not very efficient because for each element you are iterating through the list again to get the count.

```
List<PicInfo> pi = new List<PicInfo>();
IEnumerable<PicInfo> filt = pi.Where(x=>pi.Count(z=>z.FileName==x.FileName)>1);
```

I hope the code isn't too complicated to need explaining. I always think its best to work it out on your own anyway but if anythign is confusing then just ask and I'll explain.

If you want the second filter to be filtering for the same filename and same hash being a duplicate then you just need to extend the lambda in the Count to check against hash too.

Obviously if you just want filenames at the end then it is easy enough to do a `Select` to get just an enumerable list of those filenames, possibly with a `Distinct` if you only want them to appear once.

NB. Code written by hand so do forgive typos. May not compile first time, etc. ;-)

**Edit to explain code - spoilers! ;-)**

In english what we want to do is the following:

> for each item in the list we want to select it if and only if there is more than one item in the list with the same filename.

Breaking this down to iterate over the list and select things based on a criteria we use the Where method. The condition of our where method is

> there is more than one item in the list with the same filename

for this we clearly need to count the list so we use pi.Count. However we have a condition that we are only counting if the filename matches so we pass in an expression to tell it only to count those things.

The expression will work on each item of the list and return true if we want to count it and false if we don't want to.

The filename we are interested in is on x, the item we are filtering. So we want to count how many items have a filename the same as x.FileName. Thus our expression is `z=>z.FileName==x.FileName`. So z is our variable in this expression and x.FileName in this context is unchanging as we iterate over z.

We then of course put our criteria in of >1 to get the boolean value we want.

<s>If you wanted those that are duplicates when considering the filename and hashvalue then you would expand the part in the Count to be `z=>z.FileName==x.FileName && z.hashValue==x.hashValue`.</s>

<s>So your final code to get the distinct on both values would be:</s>

<s>List pi = new List();</s>
<s>List filt = pi.Where(x=>pi.Count(z=>z.FileName==x.FileName && z.hashValue==x.hashValue)>1).ToList();</s>

If you wanted those that are duplicates when considering the filename and hashvalue then you would expand the part in the Count to compare the hashValue as well. Since this is an array you will want to use the [SequenceEqual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567.aspx) method to compare them value by value.

So your final code to get the distinct on both values would be:

```
List<PicInfo> pi = new List<PicInfo>();
List<PicInfo> filt = pi.Where(x=>pi.Count(z=>z.FileName==x.FileName && z.hashValue.SequenceEqual(x.hashValue))>1).ToList();
```

Note that I didn't create the intermediary list and just went straight from the original list. You could go from the intermediate list but the code would be much the same if going from the original as from a filtered list.

Comment: i need it as the generic list, and i need to get the list with all the duplicate file names. i dont want them to appear once in the list.

Comment: What you will get out of the above code is an IEnumerable<PicInfo> with all of the PicInfo objects with a duplicate filename. It won't give you one copy. I'm not sure what generic List you want though. A generic List of the filenames will presumably be a List<string> but I'm not sure then why you'd want them appearing multiple times. If you want a list of PicInfo then you just need to call ToList() to get one.

Comment: ya i need the picinfo. so i'll do the .Tolist() function at the end. so with this line i get all the objects that have the same file name right?

Comment: Yup. I'll update the question with an explanation of how it works if you're still having trouble following it. :)

Comment: you're totally right about that secondarily filter. it would be neater to do that in the same linq line and original list. Also thank you very much for the explanation!

Comment: Cool. Linq is a lot of fun. :)

Comment: comparing byte[] array fails. if i strip it to 2 lines of code, the comparision for file names works. but for the hash value's which is a byte[] array doesnt work in linq?

Comment: @Yustme: Ah, I forgot that it was an array. It will be having trouble working out equality. You probably want to use SequenceEquals (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567.aspx) to compare the byte arrays. See update in answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
        var p = pi.GroupBy(rs => rs.fileName) // group by name
            .Where(rs => rs.Count() > 1) // find group whose count greater than 1
            .Select(rs => rs.First()) // select 1st element from each group
            .GroupBy(rs => rs.hashValue) // now group by hash value
            .Where(rs => rs.Count() > 1) // find group has multiple values
            .Select(rs => rs.First()) // select first element from group
            .ToList<PicInfo>() // make the list of picInfo of result
```

Comment: If there are duplicates, i want them all to be returned, not just one of them. Isn't that what 'First()' will do? just return one of the duplicate? Also, this is an anonymous type. It needs to be a generic list.

Comment: @Yustme: _"Also, this is an anonymous type. It needs to be a generic list."_ => Then use at the end of the Linq query: `ToList<PicInfo>()`.

Comment: i figured that one out thanks, but how about the function "First"? does that only return 1 item, or both if the names and hash values are equal?

Comment: The GroupBy method will return a sequence of groups, each group comprising of those things with the same filename. The rs.First will thus get the first PicInfo for a given group. That means you will only end up with one PicInfo per filename which I don't think is what you want. I suspect there is a method that will take all of them and put them back into a sequence but I can't think what it is offhand.

Comment: i was trying out All(), but that function doesnt take 0 arguments. Im not sure what to pass it as arguments. This would be exactly what i need. both file names and hash values have been checked.

Comment: I guess what you are expecting is list of all duplicate items which has same filename and HashValue

Comment: no i expect a list of objects from picinfo. because i still need to know their path which i wouldn't have if i only get filename and hash code.